# JavaScript changing color of Class when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, class, button

I can't seem to get document.getElementsByClassName to work, when I click a button. I can get the document.getElementById to work, but not class.
Can someone explain to me why the class one below is not working please?

```
document.getElementById('footer').style.background = 'rgba(189, 195, 199,1.0)';
document.getElementsByClassName('menulink').style.background = 'rgba(189, 195, 199,1.0)';
```

I have set the classes in my html page:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="menulink" href="index3.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a class="menulink" href="#">Coca Cola</a></li>
                <li><a class="menulink" href="#">Sprite</a></li>
                <li><a class="menulink" href="#">Dr Pepper</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Document.getElementsByClassName()

#### [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names.

---

This is returning an object, not just one value. You'll have to reference them the same way you reference any property of an object.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className')["propertyName"].*action here*;
```

In your case something like this might work:

```
   var targets = document.getElementsByClassName("menulink");
   for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
      targets[i].style.background = "rgba(189, 195, 199,1.0)";
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementById returns a single element, but getElementsByClassName() returns a NodeList (notice the 's' on getElementS). 
This would work:

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('menulink')[0].style.background = 'rgba(189, 195, 199,1.0)';
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementByClassName returns list of DOM element.

You have to iterate to each item and need to set style e.g

```
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('menulink');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        links[i].style.background = 'rgba(189, 195, 199,1.0)';
    }
```